# Is there a way to have Alexa keep the microphone on in my skill?

Tags: alexa

Is there a way to write a skill (similar to "Alexa, Guard") to have Alexa keep the microphone on when the user opens the skill.

I would like to make an app that listens for a baby's babble and has Alexa do things when it hears a particular babble pattern (NOT WORDS).

Comment: I don't think you'll get this to work, I'm not aware of any Alexa API that will pass you the audio to analyse let alone let you hold the microphone open.